Swift: appendingPathComponent does not work after unwrap base Url
I implemented some functions to get Url, but I can not do get completed url after unwrap the base url. I have these two variable as follows:
var baseUrl: URL? {
        switch self{
        case .getNews:
            if let url = URL(string: "https://api.lil.software"){
                return url
            }else{
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    
var path: String? {
    return "/news"
}

I want to get the completed Url, so I implemented a function as follows
var urlRequest: URLRequest? {
        if var url = self.baseUrl, var path = self.path{
            return URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathExtension(path))
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }

When I call endpoint.urlRequest! I think I should get "https://api.lil.software/news", but I got "https://api.lil.software"
However, if I implemented var urlRequest: URLRequest? without unwrapping base url as follows, I can get the completed url like "https://api.lil.software/news"
var urlRequest: URLRequest? {
        return URLRequest(url: self.baseUrl!.appendingPathComponent(self.path!))
    }

Why there is different? because of if var? thank you for your help.
I tried to use guard let/var etc, but I have the same result. I used the wrong way? thank you for your response.

You are testing appendingPathComponent() vs appendingPathExtension()... You aren't testing the same method, hence the different results...

You want url.appending(path:path), not url.appendingPathExtension(path)
A path extension is something like .jpg and can only be appended to a non-empty path.
The success of your second code block is not because you have force unwrapped the strings, but because you have used appendingPathComponent.
AppendingPathComponent will check the file system to determine if the path refers to a directory and if so, it will append a trailing /. In this case you aren't working with file paths, so appending(path:) is slightly more efficient as it will not check the file system, by default.
You can simplify your code too, since you are returning optionals, there is no need to explicitly check for nil and then return nil
var baseUrl: URL? {
    switch self {
        case .getNews:
            return URL(string: "https://api.lil.software")
    }
}

var path: String? {
    return "/news"
}

var urlRequest: URLRequest? {
     guard let url = self.baseUrl, let path = self.path else {
        return nil
     }
     return URLRequest(url: url.appending(path:path))
}

